# Set optional property's type depending on Required property's type in Interface

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I'm making an interface and would like to force one of my parameter's types to be either an array of objects or an array of strings. Then i have a second parameter that is optionally passed depending on the type of the first parameter.

more specifically i have code that looks something like:

```
export interface someClassProps<T extends object> {
    list: Array<T | string | number> ;

    value?: keyof T | Array<string | number>;
    name?: keyof T | Array<string | number>;
    disable?: keyof T | Array<boolean | number>;

}

class someClass extends React.Component<someClassProps> {

    constructor(props: someClassProps) {
        super(props);
    }
}
```

I would like to make sure that if list is of type `Array<T>`, then value, name, and disabled are either of type `keyof T`, or they are `undefined`. I'm pretty sure that will work with the current code.

I also need value and list to be an Array of the same type or value needs to be undefined.

It looks like typescript doesn't allow you to compare values, so I'm not sure how to go about checking this.

I was planning on just having a method in `someClass` that compares the types list, value, name, and disable using generics, but that doesn't seem allowed. Should i use `typeof list === typeof value` instead of trying to compare types directly?

Comment: `type someClassProperties = {list: Array<object>; value: string} | {list: Array<string>};`?  Or `type someClassProperties<T extends object> = {list: Array<T>; value: keyof T} | {list: Array<string>}?` It depends on the use case.

Comment: @jcalz Oh interesting. I guess the actual ideal case would be for me to be able to use a generic on the list type (restricted to object/string), and then use whatever type is passed in to array for a few of the properties.

Comment: If you want something more than what I posted in the comment, please edit your question with some code showing how you intend to use `someClassProperties`.

Comment: @jcalz I've further figured out what i need to get done, and updated the question to be much more specific and to include what i've currently tried.

Comment: Heh, I think I understand it less now: "I would like to make sure that if list is of type Array<T>, then value... [is] either of type keyof T, or [is] undefined" and "I also need value and list to be an Array of the same type or value needs to be undefined." seem like contradictory requirements to me.